# The level of the man is determined by his wife Talmud

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

I remember learning something like the following in [Gemara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara) shiur.

> That if the man is not good and his wife is good, he will be good
>
> And that if the man is good and his wife is not good, he will be not good

Please help me with the source (and the exact statement).

Comment: Is it possible you're referring to the Talmud Bavli in Sotah 2B where it states in the name of Resh Laqish that a woman is paired with a man according to his deeds (אין מזווגין לו לאדם אשה אלא לפי מעשיו)?

Comment: @lee thank you, but it is not this

Comment: I see it referenced here http://www.jewfaq.org/women.htm but without a source. I will keep looking.

Comment: @danno thank you, yes this is it, The Talmud says that when a pious man marries a wicked woman, the man becomes wicked, but when a wicked man marries a pious woman, the man becomes pious.

Comment: found this Genesis Rabbah 17:7

Comment: There is a gemara that talks about a woman who was married to a Tzaddik, and used to wrap his tefillin on his arm every morning. Then he died and she married a tax collector, and she would tie his armband on his arm every morning. I don't remember all the details, but I think it was related to the idea in the question.

Comment: @Menachem see link in my comment to the first answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is it:

http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.17.7?lang=en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all

Genesis Rabbah 17:7

A story [is told] of a pious man and his wife who could not have kids. They said: we are of no benefit to the Holy of of Blessing, so they divorced. He went and married a wicked woman, and she made him wicked; and she went and married a wicked man, and she made him righteous. Thus: everything is from the woman.

Comment: but on the other hand "a woman is influenced by her husband." http://halakhah.com/zarah/zarah_39.html#39a_32

Comment: Do the kiruv professionals know this trick?

Comment: Can you explain the middle portion to me? "He replied: at first, He created her, and Adam saw her full of secretions and blood. He kept her away from him, and went back and created her a second time. She said to him: I will add further, I was meant to marry my mother's brother, but because I grew up in the same house as him, I was unattractive in his eyes, and he went and married a different woman, who is less attractive than I am."

Answer (score 3):

סנהדרין קט: וקי

The Gemara there describes how קורח was influenced by his wife against his better judgement, and how און בן פלת was saved by his wife contrary to his initial plans.